# Calculate date diff in Eloquent where clause Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, datediff

In my Laravel 5 app I've got a relationship, and from this one-to-many relationship, I want to query and get only results whose date diff between their creation_date and an arbitrary date is between 0 and 2 days.

If you need I can show you a pseudocode, even if I think that it's clear what I need.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a arbitrary date using carbon (as you are using laravel):

```
$start = Carbon\Carbon::create(year,month,day);

$end = $start->copy()->addDays(2);
```

And a little DB::raw in the mix, to format the created_at field to your needs:

```
Model::where(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")'),'>=',$start)->where(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")'),'<=',$end)->get();
```

That's it.

Comment: For example, I have this where clause:

->where('updated_at', '>=', new \DateTime($lastDateCheckin))

Where $lastDateCheckin is my arbitrary date.

If I compare with "updated_at" like this, it doesn't work as I want, because it considers also minutes and seconds. I want to consider only updated_at Y-m-d.

Comment: The call setTime(0, 0, 0) on datetime object before passing it to the query for the lower end of the range, or setTime(23,59,59) for the high end of the range. created_at is stored in the database as date+time, so you need to consider time part as well.

Comment: Adjusted the answer to fit your description. @Bellots